# Spring Integration file adapter tests failing on macOS

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, macos-big-sur

I have a spring integration project with multiple tests that runs perfectly fine on Windows and Linux machines. Now, I've just bought a MacBook and tried running the tests on it. All of my file adapter tests (15) are failing.

The below example test verifies that when a file is placed in the `inboundOutDirectory` directory, that it's properly processed.

Test class example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
        initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class,
        classes = {StructuralEnricherIntegrationFlow.class, StructuralEnricherIntegrationFlowTests.Config.class})
@SpringIntegrationTest
@DirtiesContext
public class StructuralEnricherIntegrationFlowTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockIntegrationContext mockIntegrationContext;

    @Autowired
    private File inboundOutDirectory;

    @Autowired
    private File inboundProcessedDirectory;

    @Autowired
    private File inboundFailedDirectory;

    @Autowired
    private PollableChannel testChannel;

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(inboundOutDirectory);
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(inboundProcessedDirectory);
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(inboundFailedDirectory);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStructuralEnricherFlowEmptyResponse() throws Exception {
        // given
        String docId = "xxx";

        // when
        MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = mockMessageHandler().handleNextAndReply(m -> "{}");
        this.mockIntegrationContext.substituteMessageHandlerFor("structuralEnricherEndpoint", mockMessageHandler);            
        String fileName = TestingUtils.createFileAggregated(docId, 1, ".json", inboundOutDirectory,
                "{}");

        // then
        Message<String> receive = (Message<String>) testChannel.receive(3000);
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(String.format("{xxx"),
                receive.getPayload(), JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
        assertTrue(FileUtils.getFile(new File(this.inboundProcessedDirectory, fileName)).exists());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    public static class Config {

        @Autowired
        private File inboundOutDirectory;

        @Bean
        public PollableChannel testChannel() {
            return new QueueChannel();
        }

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow processedDirectory(@Value("${pattern}") String pattern) {
            return IntegrationFlows
                    .from(Files.inboundAdapter(inboundOutDirectory)
                                    .regexFilter(pattern)
                                    .useWatchService(true)
                                    .watchEvents(FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE),
                            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
                    .transform(Files.toStringTransformer())
                    .channel("testChannel")
                    .get();
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the testChannel never receives a message as I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at `receive.getPayload()`. I've tried increasing the timeout but it didn't help.

System info:

- spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.4.RELEASE
- MacBook Pro 13 (2020) with macOS Big Sur 11.1
- openjdk version "1.8.0_275"

The same test works for example on ubuntu with java version 1.8.0_275.

I'm not sure what's the problem so hopefully, you can help me out.

**UPDATE**

So it seems that the problem lies in the *useWatchService(true)* in the *Files.inboundAdapter*. This is how the processing of the document is currently triggered:

```
return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Files.inboundAdapter(inboundOutDirectory)
                        .regexFilter(intermediatePattern)
                        .useWatchService(true)
                        .watchEvents(FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE,
                                FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.DELETE),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)
                        .taskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(5)))
```

I have debugged this flow a bit more and it appears that when *.useWatchService(true)*, then the adapter will pick up the file with a delay (it takes about 10 seconds). Not sure why it works differently on macOS. When I change it to *.useWatchService(false)*, it works instantly.

Here is the util method that creates the files:

```
public static String createFileAggregated(String id, Integer documentId, String extension, File tmpDir, String content) throws Exception {
    String filename = String.format("%s%04d%s", id, documentId, extension);
    FileUtils.write(new File(tmpDir, filename), (Optional.ofNullable(content).orElse(filename)), "UTF-8", false);
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can share with us the whole project to play with. What you show so far is not a whole picture and we can't reproduce.

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to see if there are any clues. We have a test case [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/335a30c0f06391c740c67049829acbd042337ada/spring-integration-file/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/file/WatchServiceDirectoryScannerTests.java#L76-L83) and I do all my development on MacOS (Catalina - I've not yet upgraded to Big Sur) with no problems. Is it a new Mac (M1 chip)?

Comment: Also it is not clear what is that `TestingUtils.createFileAggregated()` and so on.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for the prompt answers. I'm not on M1 chip. Please take a look at the UPDATE in my question, hope it helps a bit. Let me know if I still need to create a sample project (it will take me some time...).

Comment: Reading the javadoc of WatchService it might make sense. It says that it's platform-dependent so I guess it behaves differently when it comes to events on macOS.